# undefined reference to void "function" C++

Tags: c++, reference, header

I got the following error:

```
features.cpp:(.text+0x4f6): undefined reference to `void Convolve<float>(CImageOf<float>, CImageOf<float>&, CImageOf<float>)'
```

So, in my features.cpp file, I added the following header file, with the content:

```
template <class T>
void Convolve(CImageOf<T> src, CImageOf<T>& dst,
              CFloatImage kernel);
```

I'm compiling this with GCC on ubuntu 64bit. I realize that the error above is because what is in my header does not match the reference, but that's because of the template, and so I shouldnt be having this problem right? What else is going on?

I double checked my calls to convolve, and actually this is the types I'm using :

```
Convolve(CFloatImage, CFloatImage, CFloatImage);
```

I can't actually find any reference to the error above

Comment: CFloatImage kernel != CImageOf<float>

Comment: Looks like you put in header template function __declaration__ only, not __definition__. Where `Convolve` body is defined? And `CFloatImage` is just `typedef` for `CImageOf<float>`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As turned out in a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17003/discussion-between-nobody-and-mugetsu) with the OP the problem was probably in a Makefile that did not link correctly.

There was no definition but a declaration of the template in the .h file (as some of you suggested). I think the OP confused the terms.

However there was a definition of the template in the .cpp file along with a (non template) function definition that instantiated `Convolve<float>` (and others).

So to repeat it: The code was correct but the build routine was not.

Answer (score 4):

If you put a function template into a .cpp file and use it in a different translation unit, you need to explicitly instantiate the template, e.g.:

```
template
void Convolve<float>(
   CImageOf<float> src,
   CImageOf<float>& dst,
   CFloatImage kernel);
```

Basically, the compiler can instantiate a templte only when it has seen its definition. If you want the template to be instantiated automatically, you need to define it in a header.

Comment: i did not put the template in a .cpp file. I define the above in a header

Comment: In this case, the template you are using is defined somewhere else and not instantiated. The compiler clearly thinks that you are correctly calling a function template which is declared somewhere but which isn't defined. Are you including all necessary library when building the executable?