# strange undefined references to function, the function call does not exist C++

Tags: c++, header

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [undefined reference to void “function” C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546420/undefined-reference-to-void-function-c)

I get the error :

```
undefined reference to `void Convolve<float>(CImageOf<float>, CImageOf<float>&, CImageOf<float>)'   features.cpp    /cv-pj      C/C++ Problem
```

However, doing a global search I cannot find any instance where I call convolve with those types.

This is what's in my header:

```
template <class T>
void Convolve(CImageOf<T> src, CImageOf<T>& dst,
              CFloatImage kernel);
```

What could be wrong? Note this actually compiles on windows, but I'm on ubuntu 64bit gcc

Edit: im on eclipse and it shows that the error is on line 0. What does that mean?

Full error:

```
features.o: In function `computeHarrisValues(CImageOf<float>&, CImageOf<float>&)':
features.cpp:(.text+0x4f6): undefined reference to `void Convolve<float>(CImageOf<float>, CImageOf<float>&, CImageOf<float>)'
features.cpp:(.text+0x63e): undefined reference to `void Convolve<float>(CImageOf<float>, CImageOf<float>&, CImageOf<float>)'
features.cpp:(.text+0xa60): undefined reference to `void Convolve<float>(CImageOf<float>, CImageOf<float>&, CImageOf<float>)'
features.cpp:(.text+0xbd1): undefined reference to `void Convolve<float>(CImageOf<float>, CImageOf<float>&, CImageOf<float>)'
features.cpp:(.text+0xd42): undefined reference to `void Convolve<float>(CImageOf<float>, CImageOf<float>&, CImageOf<float>)'
features.o:features.cpp:(.text+0x460b): more undefined references to `void Convolve<float>(CImageOf<float>, CImageOf<float>&, CImageOf<float>)' follow
features.o: In function `ComputeMOPSDescriptors(CImageOf<float>&, FeatureSet&)':
features.cpp:(.text+0x533e): undefined reference to `void ConvolveSeparable<float>(CImageOf<float>, CImageOf<float>&, CImageOf<float>, CImageOf<float>, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Features] Error 1
```

Comment: At some place, you mistyped the `kernel` argument.

Comment: @DanielFischer can't find it, this compiles in windows. I'm on ubuntu with gcc

Comment: Doesn't gcc tell you compilation unit the undefined reference is coming from? Could you please post the full error message (including filenames)?

Comment: Okay, was just a guess since the types for that argument didn't match.

Comment: @Nobody no it refers to line 0 in my code

Comment: You are looking into the problems tab in eclipse, am I right? You should rather have a look at the console tab where the complete compiler output will be shown. There you should see much more (unfiltered) information (which I was asking for).

Comment: So look at `computeHarrisValues`.

Comment: So you can see it is in `features.cpp`. What is the type `CFloatImage`? Is it `typedef CImageOf<float> CFloatImage`?

Comment: @Nobody I checked it in those function, and the kernel types are all CFloatImage. It is typedef CImageOf<float> CFloatImage;

Comment: well then the call `Convolve(CFloatImage,CFloatImage,CFloatImage);` is the same as `Convolve(CImageOf<float>,CImageOf<float>,CImageOf<float>);` (the typedefed types are interchangable) so you *did* call the function there.

Comment: @Nobody but why I am having this error?

Comment: Probably for the reason stated in the answer to your other (duplicate) question.

Comment: @Nobody no, I put my definition in a header, not in the actual c++ file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17003/discussion-between-nobody-and-mugetsu)

Answer (score 1):

```
template
void Convolve<float>(
   CImageOf<float> src,
   CImageOf<Float>& dst,
   CFloatImage kernel);
```

Comment: I think it should be `template <>`. And you should give more detail about the meaning of these lines.